# Get rid of the borders on hover

Tags: html, css

I've created a small button with multiple borders, and on the hover of it, I'm able to see a smooth transition of color. I am unable to get rid of the borders when I hover over them. Currently when I hover, the color and background color changes, but the borders doesn't go off.

Here is my code.

```css
.c-btn--lg {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  border: none;
  font-family: titling-gothic-fb-compressed, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  min-width: 14.5rem;
  padding: 1.6rem 2rem;
}

.c-btn--primary {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #382f2d;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.c-btn--primary:before {
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 0;
}

.c-btn--primary:after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0.5rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.5rem;
}

.c-btn--primary:after,
.c-btn--primary:beforee {
  border: 0.1rem solid #382f2d;
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.c-btn--primary:after,
.c-btn--primary:before {
  border: 0.1rem solid #382f2d;
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.c-btn--primary:focus,
.c-btn--primary:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #d1ccbd, inset 1rem 7rem 0 0 #d1ccbd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #d1ccbd, inset 1rem 7rem 0 0 #d1ccbd;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="submitwrapper">
<button class="c-age-gate__submit c-btn c-btn--primary c-btn--lg" type="submit">ENTER</button>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the borders to "smoothly" disappear, but you can get rid of them with these selectors:

```
.c-btn--primary:hover::after,
.c-btn--primary:hover::before {
  border: none;
}
```

```css
.c-btn--lg {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  border: none;
  font-family: titling-gothic-fb-compressed, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  min-width: 14.5rem;
  padding: 1.6rem 2rem;
}

.c-btn--primary {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #382f2d;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.c-btn--primary:before {
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 0;
}

.c-btn--primary:after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0.5rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.5rem;
}

.c-btn--primary:after,
.c-btn--primary:before {
  border: 0.1rem solid #382f2d;
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.c-btn--primary:focus,
.c-btn--primary:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #d1ccbd, inset 1rem 7rem 0 0 #d1ccbd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #d1ccbd, inset 1rem 7rem 0 0 #d1ccbd;
  color:white;
}

.c-btn--primary:hover::after,
.c-btn--primary:hover::before
{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="submitwrapper">
<button class="c-age-gate__submit c-btn c-btn--primary c-btn--lg" type="submit">ENTER</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it "smoothly" with an `rgba` color.

```css
.c-btn--lg {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  border: none;
  font-family: titling-gothic-fb-compressed, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  min-width: 14.5rem;
  padding: 1.6rem 2rem;
}

.c-btn--primary {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #382f2d;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.c-btn--primary:before {
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 0;
}

.c-btn--primary:after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0.5rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.5rem;
}

.c-btn--primary:after,
.c-btn--primary:before {
  border: 0.1rem solid rgba(56, 47, 45, 1);
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.c-btn--primary:focus,
.c-btn--primary:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #d1ccbd, inset 1rem 7rem 0 0 #d1ccbd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #d1ccbd, inset 1rem 7rem 0 0 #d1ccbd;
  color:white;
}

.c-btn--primary:hover::after,
.c-btn--primary:hover::before {
  border-color: rgba(56, 47, 45, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="submitwrapper">
<button class="c-age-gate__submit c-btn c-btn--primary c-btn--lg" type="submit">ENTER</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this to your code:

```
.c-btn--primary:hover::after,
.c-btn--primary:hover::before {
  border: none;
}
```